# Disable multiple button clicks works but is not updating my data

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-blade

I am trying to prevent a button to be clicked multiple times to avoid resending requests. The disabling works but my data to be sent or updated is not executed.

```
<form class="detail_form" method="POST" action="{{ url('update', $id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
    <button class="btn btn-update accntfrm_btn" type="submit" id="btn-update">Update</button>
</form>

$("#btn-update").on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function(){el.prop('disabled', false); }, 3000);
});
```

How can I execute my updates and disallow the multiple clicks at the same time?

Comment: where is your ajax to submit the form?

Comment: @M.Hemant I'm not using ajax in submitting the form. It's plain php. I'm using js only in disallowing multiple clicks.

Comment: If you don’t know what `event.preventDefault()` does, go look it up …

Comment: @04FS What do you mean?

Comment: You either know what this does, or you don’t. Since you are basically complaining about it doing its job as is to be expected, it is probably the latter, so … go read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this in action attribute of Form,

```
{{ route('update', ['id'=>$id]) }}
```

I guess it is your route,

```
Route::post('/update/{id}','YourController@your_function')->name('update');
```

and in your controller,

```
   public function your_function(Request $request, $id){ // your code }
```

and if you want to go pure laravel,

use `Form` class

```
    {!! Form::open(['route' => ['update', 'id'=>$id], 'files' => true, 'class' => 'detail_form']) !!}
```

Comment: Nope it's not. If I remove `id="btn-update"` it works well. Thanks anyway.

Comment: thts because you're basically disabling this before submitting to the server side script

Answer (score 0):

```
event.preventDefault();
```

prevents default action of the form, this means that your form is not going to submit to the server. what you can do is use ajax or maybe axios if you have it installed to send your information to the server. Since you obviously have jquery, you can make an ajax request to your server to update your information like so

```
`const route = "{{ route('update', $id)}}";`
```

or
    `const route = "/route/to/your/server";`

```
`$.post(route, 
        {//add a body if you need to send some information to the server
          //it is optional}, 
        function(data, status){// in this callback you can create a feedback 
                               //from a successful trip to and from the server 
                               //for your users

                })`
```

`.fail(function(error){
                        //in this callback you can handle errors from a failed trip 
                        //to and from the server
                    });`

Comment: _“what you can do is use ajax or maybe axios”_ … or maybe just not prevent the event default, if the event default should not be prevented …